# Cannot build the HelloWorld Poco Example Program on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, hyperlink, g++, poco-libraries

I've just installed Poco on Ubuntu (by compiling from the code on the git master branch at release 1.9.0). And now I'm trying to compile my HelloWorld.cpp.

This is what I've tried:

```
g++  -L/usr/local/lib -lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil -lPocoNet -lPocoNetd -lPocoData -lPocoXML ./helloworld.cpp
```

This is the helloworld.cpp content:

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServer.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace Poco;
using namespace Poco::Net;
using namespace Poco::Util;

class HelloRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
{
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        app.logger().information("Request from %s", request.clientAddress().toString());

        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        response.send()
            << "<html>"
            << "<head><title>Hello</title></head>"
            << "<body><h1>Hello from the POCO Web Server</h1></body>"
            << "</html>";
    }
};

class HelloRequestHandlerFactory: public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
    HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest&)
    {
        return new HelloRequestHandler;
    }
};

class WebServerApp: public ServerApplication
{
    void initialize(Application& self)
    {
        loadConfiguration();
        ServerApplication::initialize(self);
    }

    int main(const std::vector<std::string>&)
    {
        UInt16 port = static_cast<UInt16>(config().getUInt("port", 8080));

        HTTPServer srv(new HelloRequestHandlerFactory, port);
        srv.start();
        logger().information("HTTP Server started on port %hu.", port);
        waitForTerminationRequest();
        logger().information("Stopping HTTP Server...");
        srv.stop();

        return Application::EXIT_OK;
    }
};

POCO_SERVER_MAIN(WebServerApp)
```

I expect by keeping adding the libraries I link in the g++ command line it should eventually allow me to compile the program.

But it seems no matter how many libraries I tried to link I'm still getting the following errors (without eliminating any of the errors with how many libraries I add on the way):

```
kennyyu@kennyyu-ubuntu:~/poco/myexample$ g++  -L/usr/local/lib -lPocoFoundation -lPocoUtil -lPocoNet -lPocoNetd -lPocoData -lPocoXML ./helloworld.cpp
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::run(int, char**)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `Poco::Exception::displayText[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImpl4hostEv[_ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImpl4hostEv]+0x28): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImpl4hostEv[_ZNK4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImpl4hostEv]+0x2e): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::ReferenceCounter::ReferenceCounter()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco16ReferenceCounterC2Ev[_ZN4Poco16ReferenceCounterC5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `Poco::AtomicCounter::AtomicCounter(int)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Logger::log(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Message::Priority)':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE[_ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE]+0xa0): undefined reference to `Poco::Message::Message(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Message::Priority)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE[_ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE]+0xbe): undefined reference to `Poco::Message::~Message()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE[_ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_7Message8PriorityE]+0xd2): undefined reference to `Poco::Message::~Message()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Logger::information(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Any const&)':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco6Logger11informationERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_3AnyE[_ZN4Poco6Logger11informationERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_3AnyE]+0x37): undefined reference to `Poco::format(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Any const&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Util::Application::logger() const':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZNK4Poco4Util11Application6loggerEv[_ZNK4Poco4Util11Application6loggerEv]+0x30): undefined reference to `Poco::Bugcheck::nullPointer(char const*, char const*, int)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Util::Application::instance()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv[_ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv]+0x7): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::_pInstance'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv[_ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv]+0x24): undefined reference to `Poco::Bugcheck::nullPointer(char const*, char const*, int)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv[_ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv]+0x2b): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::_pInstance'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `HelloRequestHandler::handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest&, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse&)':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE[_ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE]+0x73): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::SocketAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE[_ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE]+0x100): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::setChunkedTransferEncoding(bool)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE[_ZN19HelloRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE]+0x139): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::setContentType(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `HelloRequestHandler::HelloRequestHandler()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN19HelloRequestHandlerC2Ev[_ZN19HelloRequestHandlerC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler::HTTPRequestHandler()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `WebServerApp::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&)':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp10initializeERN4Poco4Util11ApplicationE[_ZN12WebServerApp10initializeERN4Poco4Util11ApplicationE]+0x1d): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::loadConfiguration(int)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp10initializeERN4Poco4Util11ApplicationE[_ZN12WebServerApp10initializeERN4Poco4Util11ApplicationE]+0x30): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `HelloRequestHandlerFactory::HelloRequestHandlerFactory()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN26HelloRequestHandlerFactoryC2Ev[_ZN26HelloRequestHandlerFactoryC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `WebServerApp::main(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x7c): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::AbstractConfiguration::getUInt(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int) const'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0xb6): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::HTTPServerParams()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x11d): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::HTTPServer(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory> >, unsigned short, Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams>)'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x14a): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::TCPServer::start()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x1f6): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::waitForTerminationRequest()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x273): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::TCPServer::stop()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x287): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::~HTTPServer()'
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE[_ZN12WebServerApp4mainERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS6_EE]+0x3a4): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::~HTTPServer()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `WebServerApp::WebServerApp()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerAppC2Ev[_ZN12WebServerAppC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::ServerApplication()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::ReferenceCounter::~ReferenceCounter()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco16ReferenceCounterD2Ev[_ZN4Poco16ReferenceCounterD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `Poco::AtomicCounter::~AtomicCounter()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x20): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::name() const'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x30): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::uninitialize()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x38): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::reinitialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x40): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::defineOptions(Poco::Util::OptionSet&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x48): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::run()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12WebServerApp[_ZTV12WebServerApp]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::handleOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `WebServerApp::~WebServerApp()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN12WebServerAppD2Ev[_ZN12WebServerAppD5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::~ServerApplication()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `HelloRequestHandlerFactory::~HelloRequestHandlerFactory()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN26HelloRequestHandlerFactoryD2Ev[_ZN26HelloRequestHandlerFactoryD5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory::~HTTPRequestHandlerFactory()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `HelloRequestHandler::~HelloRequestHandler()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN19HelloRequestHandlerD2Ev[_ZN19HelloRequestHandlerD5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler::~HTTPRequestHandler()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD2Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o: In function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
helloworld.cpp:(.text._ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD2Ev[_ZN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplD5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI12WebServerApp[_ZTI12WebServerApp]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Util::ServerApplication'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI26HelloRequestHandlerFactory[_ZTI26HelloRequestHandlerFactory]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI19HelloRequestHandler[_ZTI19HelloRequestHandler]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
/tmp/ccWTd1HS.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref._ZTIN4Poco9ExceptionE[DW.ref._ZTIN4Poco9ExceptionE]+0x0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Exception'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
kennyyu@kennyyu-ubuntu:~/poco/myexample$
```

```
kennyyu@kennyyu-ubuntu:~/poco/myexample$ ls /usr/local/lib/libPoco*.so
/usr/local/lib/libPocoCppParserd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoDataMySQL.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoDataSQLited.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundationd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoMongoDBd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoPDFd.so    /usr/local/lib/libPocoUtild.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoZipd.so
/usr/local/lib/libPocoCppParser.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoDataODBCd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoDataSQLite.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoMongoDB.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoPDF.so     /usr/local/lib/libPocoUtil.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoZip.so
/usr/local/lib/libPocoDatad.so       /usr/local/lib/libPocoDataODBC.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoEncodingsd.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoJSONd.so        /usr/local/lib/libPocoNetd.so      /usr/local/lib/libPocoRedisd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoXMLd.so
/usr/local/lib/libPocoDataMySQLd.so  /usr/local/lib/libPocoData.so       /usr/local/lib/libPocoEncodings.so    /usr/local/lib/libPocoJSON.so         /usr/local/lib/libPocoNet.so       /usr/local/lib/libPocoRedis.so   /usr/local/lib/libPocoXML.so
kennyyu@kennyyu-ubuntu:~/poco/myexample$
```

Can someone please shed me some light?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 19.10.

```
sudo apt install libpoco-dev
```

(All of the Poco libraries get installed with that.)

Create helloworld.cpp with contents from OP.

Compile with:

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.o -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil
```

If that still doesn't work, you can include the location where the Poco .h files are with the -I option, and where the Poco .so files are with the -L option.

Find where the Poco .so files are located:

```
sudo find / -name "libPoco*.so" 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libPocoFoundation.so
...

sudo find / -name "ServerSocket.h" 2>/dev/null
/usr/include/Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h
```

The compile statement then becomes:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/Poco/ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil
```